# How to paste range of cells in the next empty table row?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy a range of cells from one table to another on a different sheet, but when it pastes to the new table it overrides existing information.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim db As Worksheet

Dim lCopy As Long
Dim lDest As Long

Dim lCopy2 As Long
Dim lDest2 As Long

Set db = Sheet1

db.range("B6:F1000").ClearContents

  Sheets("Create_kit").range("B4").Value = Sheets("Update_kit").range("B3").Value
  Sheets("Create_kit").range("C4").Value = Sheets("Update_kit").range("C3").Value

  Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Update_kit") 'Copies table
  Set wsDest = Worksheets("Create_kit") 'Pastes table

  lCopy = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  lDest = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  'Copies any cell within the table
  wsCopy.range("B5:F" & lCopy).Copy
  wsDest.range("B" & lDest).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I tried changing `Offset(1)` to `Offset(0)` but I did not notice any changes after running the code.

I would like to have the new data pasted in the next empty row in column B in the new table. I have tried to look at other asked questions but I have been unsuccessful in finding a solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Your code seems to work fine to copy a range of values to a new worksheet into the next empty row.

Comment: This is where my confusion comes in. I used this code before to copy and paste into the next empty row and it worked (as you had mentioned) but now it overrides any existing values in the table. I'm not sure what is causing it to override existing data rather then adding it to the next empty row.

Comment: Are there any empty rows in column B after your data in your "Create_kit" worksheet? If you've exceeded the max rows on the sheet, your code will start pasting over data.

Comment: Yes there are empty rows. For example, if I have added data in B6:F10 and try to run the code it will erase what is already there. There are empty rows after B6, there can be as many rows after as it is a table and it expands as new things are needed.

Comment: @MilesFett I am hoping I could use your help on this again. I was able to solve the overriding issue but I am still experiencing a problem when the values from "Create_kit" are pasted over to "Create_assembly". It pastes the values maybe 50 lines after the last entry in the table rather than in the next empty row.

Comment: I don't see `"Create_assembly"` can you update your code to include what you've changed?

Comment: Apologies, I meant to say "Update_kit" to "Create_kit". The above code is still valid, but fortunately I was able to work my way through it and make it work for what I wanted. Regardless, thankyou for your input!

Answer (score -1):

Could you confirm that in column B that you would like to copy/paste, there is no empty cell because the function you used "wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row" can find the last row where there is no empty cell in the middle.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you commented, but yes I would like to copy from column B and paste into column B of the new sheet. I am copying and pasting data from tables.

Comment: @icalderon I believe he's asking if there are any empty cells in column B. If there are, your last row is going to be found at the first empty cell.